Microsoft Graph API get users by createdDateTime
I'm trying to get users by microsoft grpah api, and all works well. I apply a filter like: $filter=startsWith(userPrincipalName,'A') and also works well. But when I added filter by createdDateTime I got an error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "1991-00-00T00:00:00",
            "request-id": "some-uuid",
            "client-request-id": "some-uuid"
        }
    }
}

In my created app in Microsoft Entra ID I have an User.Read User.ReadBasic.All only permissions. I use grant-type=password to getting token for providing graph calling. I'm trying to apply many filters and other filters also responded me with errors. In Graph explorer all works well. I believe that I got the same permissions in explorer and using token by grant-type=password. But It's wrong opinion. Anybody faced this issue?  Which permissions I need to get for filtering no only by userPrincipalName?

Does this API the one you are calling now? If so, could you pls add Directory.Read.All API permission and test again? This API permission requires admin consent. By the way, could you pls decode your token in jwt..io and see whether the scp claim contains correct permissions?

It seems to be related to User.ReadBasic.All permission. Could you try higher permission User.Read.All. Probably for some properties, you will need even higher permission like Directory.Read.All

the scp is: offline_access openid profile User.Read User.ReadBasic.All. Other permission really hard to get. It's a long process from company side. Seems I need to go throught thorny path

The "Authorization_RequestDenied" error is simply a permission issue. It indicates that the user or application does not have sufficient permissions to complete the operation. In order to filter users by createdDateTime, your application needs to have the "Directory.Read.All" permission. Admin consent is required for this permission.
